# what is the fastest way in MySQL to check foreign refference

Tags: php, mysql, database

I got a table Files

```
+------------+
| id | name  |
+------------+
+ 1  | x.jpg |
+ 2  | y.jpg |
+------------+
```

other tables refer to these files like for example

```
+---------------+-------+
| id | file_id  | user  |
+---------------+-------+
+ 1  |    2     | test  |
+ 2  |    1     | test1 |
+---------------+-------+
```

and a want to check if a file is orphanet but i don't know in which tables it is referenced. what is the fastest way to check?

Comment: Maybe take a look at referential constraints

Answer (score 2):

You would have to very explicit with your query. Lets assume you 2 other tables(`table1` and `table2`) that might contain a reference to your `Files` table.

You would

```
 SELECT Files.* FROM Files 
    LEFT JOIN table1 ON (Files.id = table1.file_id)
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON (Files.id = table2.file_id)
 WHERE
     table1.file_id IS NULL
     AND table2.file_id IS NULL
```

This query will join your other tables to your `Files` table and say "Give me results where `File.id` is not present in either table". You would have to extend this query for every table that you want to search.

Comment: Well this is not exactly what i need cause i don't know all the tables the key is referenced in, It is possible to request these from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` table which then lists al the foreign constraint table and these need to be check but speed is essential so joining them al is that performant